# How to add to `externals` all modules names that contain common name

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

In webpack I can add the following to externals:

```
externals: {
    'lib/@angular/core': 'common lib/@angular/core',
    'lib/@angular/platform-browser': 'common lib/@angular/platform-browser',
    'lib/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'common lib/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
},
```

Is there any way to specify that everything starting from `lib` should be added to `externals`, so that the above configuration can be shortened to the following:

```
externals: {
    'lib/*': 'common lib/*',
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp option:

```
externals: [
    /lib/'
]
```

However, there is currently no way to specify mapping to `'common lib/*'`. See [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4195) for more details.